# Exception on JSON parsing

Tags: android, json

My url is .php format: hostname/filename/topstory.php

While parsing, I am getting following error....

```
11-28 09:47:57.603: E/class com.example.jsonexample.AndroidJSONActivity(749): Failed to download file
11-28 09:47:57.603: W/System.err(749): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
11-28 09:47:57.638: W/System.err(749):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
    11-28 09:47:57.638: W/System.err(749):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
    11-28 09:47:57.654: W/System.err(749):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
    11-28 09:47:57.654: W/System.err(749):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
    11-28 09:47:57.667: W/System.err(749):  at com.example.jsonexample.AndroidJSONActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONActivity.java:34)
    11-28 09:47:57.673: W/System.err(749):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-28 09:47:57.673: W/System.err(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    11-28 09:47:57.673: W/System.err(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    11-28 09:47:57.673: W/System.err(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    11-28 09:47:57.683: W/System.err(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    11-28 09:47:57.683: W/System.err(749):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-28 09:47:57.683: W/System.err(749):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-28 09:47:57.698: W/System.err(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    11-28 09:47:57.698: W/System.err(749):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-28 09:47:57.698: W/System.err(749):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-28 09:47:57.698: W/System.err(749):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-28 09:47:57.698: W/System.err(749):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-28 09:47:57.698: W/System.err(749):
```

This is my code:

```
public class AndroidJSONActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdasdsadsa231",2100).show();
        String readTwitterFeed = readTwitterFeed();

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readTwitterFeed);
            Log.i(AndroidJSONActivity.class.getName(),
                "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
              Log.i(AndroidJSONActivity.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("text"));
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }




    }

    private String readTwitterFeed() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdasdsadsa231",3100).show();
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("....../video.php");

            try {

              HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

              StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
              int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

              if (statusCode == 200) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdasdsadsa",4000).show();
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  builder.append(line);
                }
              } else {
                Log.e(AndroidJSONActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
              }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdasdsa323424326a",4000).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdasdsa323424326a",4000).show();
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

my file...

```
{"view":"topstory","content":[{"story_id":"128","title":"testuser2","story_description":"

testuser2<\/p>","story_video_file":"","story_video_link":"","images":..
```

Please observe the file, it is having a line space in between the data (after

story_description":"  ),

is there any problem with that space..
 Please suggest me the solution for this....

Comment: mpost your json file and the code of the oncreate() method ( specialy line 34)

Comment: Is that the complete json file? Check your file with a json validator

Comment: It is not an full json file, in json validator, it is showing errror because of space in between data

Comment: and how do you get this json results if you exception include "Failed to download file"??

Comment: Please find the updated code..

Comment: Failed to download file"?... it is log error Log.e(AndroidJSONActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");

Comment: your exception clearly states that your download routine failed, and empty string was passed to json parser.

Comment: can u explain clearly...@marcin_j

Comment: Your error states `11-28 09:47:57.603: E/class com.example.jsonexample.AndroidJSONActivity(749): Failed to download file` which you log when the  `statusCode != 200` so the error you are showing is not a json format problem, but a problem with your http request